# Copied text using dedicated button on page contins a lot of spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I am trying to create a button that copies some text with a specific id and when that button is pressed, the text is copied, but with some blanks.

```
<p id="CopyMeID">
            mQENBF516gQBCACng7WCJ//+WP8LNdK9M8s2Q+zZFXr9SFgvkfUCIRrpRbFLZQ/f
            5jSqPSm3UqrIYfMHaUdKJgftNehbjRlsI60PSOsVBN1lwsWFg3f3f5QquM87tPTp
            VhY8q+/a5Afc9800tumQbNNoBUk1T5q23l6SZtKM9wKFQYpgJR4vgcQO2uQMsvKt
            g0TqJxrGNuTriYWVMgfNtUkzuG9v9Nsiat98+KGx316i+Nl0NOmDX/CaWYy2oOVg
            aAKn29j8K4KVWfWcrnRfvUSKibyy7Pod2OsNd9PyRCNDJf5qOT+ie9UHHWxlg6tt
            jp7pOBQiq40LFSwNpGS8NPffjSLIgbeaGW1ZABEBAAG0M1ByaW5jZU1hdHRoZXcg
            PHByaW5jZW1hdHRoZXdfc2VjdXJlQHByb3Rvbm1haWwuY29tPokBTgQTAQoAOBYh
            BNzilEPwZAXXwrBgdAQO9sKAxRKPBQJedeoEAhsDBQsJCAcCBhUKCQgLAgQWAgMB
            Ah4BAheAAAoJEAQO9sKAxRKPhX0H/1Z7d7xiAZwItGXhgIam9FxafdSmJthSVgDe
            DS2WsnWeGMuzAMCkBrkUo97aUXR5+18WCcjYr/U/baG5ycS/orNNjVLbSyqgX1Mh
            QI1bV3jZBV7Wo62iaOoWdh0ekZnmA5TjJh5M4x/2enPL4PRwqp6t11veCioNgMLM
            RAWDKJ2+YPtODbe6hgsTyd6SzQiZRohCRPOZkcUa9MO3esPut0MfefE/u0JhKNGH
            fPNH62zFyFNRkiuYTuuqaBF86EYuWmKH8JlyjPd63gCRq8IiYkYmJkQP1X+kB4Ry
            o2O/InErGAJ5ttp/Jq07CQEVbvhWnof1xB9RPOFX4I+VJMlmcEa5AQ0EXnXqBAEI
            AMLVME6dKymKVQUgDmo49PYQXvbPwPuWBZ/lQXNcLQIl6x7lwIZcp80puZ1N+s6y
            B827fVTmDx8Fu4kkE/N15iphivTJg/JQbSBRAXWyz+NTJEXR5jKekGObQve5QwbK
            QDCjKd0fk5jqpFiPmRTuhC3KKLDp1a1KuhnGOr6bln5AsHccqdcO03f6jSJisVpT
            l4N8DO96XAstk3je6GURy4FXwLWhGD46w/5sndmzkH+bIye8h1HX1Ib7u/d/+Gfw
            +c/RRq8o0rx5jFgof7b74NFsPU8vBdY+LeVNH1MEdQ5zVbbiUTn3IyjZsSYGu88O
            lQffU7LHTdyi95AWF7dYICkAEQEAAYkBNgQYAQoAIBYhBNzilEPwZAXXwrBgdAQO
            9sKAxRKPBQJedeoEAhsMAAoJEAQO9sKAxRKP8mAH/0JHf1D358+xMLglXNqsokYE
            JAmoLxrhYgYtBCPp1g35gz3HHfxHhlL1zLrAyCA82A6K2bEwMnAQsYNhmBLboSrf
            uvpLhQ4d2Q87bRasedeKwMf/t742xire6bDSFm1CbAWCs65tFt4T5GhrtPdNOKJW
            d7J3hbCiRgmIFzLEQQhctR+vJF101TsjNILzqmRmYvu1CWz4MKssFhtKJUmVp7A8
            fXpVW3w/5e2v8hmgqr65d6R/lT242VhBuYglzn27TWrLpFB1SZPiv8EVNhR1rExB
            z+bZTqHo2mgCr09y/SIFjYgJKyNiKEWJFyZK14O9EZHZ5R/IHkSBS50ENIB+NRE==6Erf
        </p>

        <h2>
            -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
        </h2>
        <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#CopyMeID')">Copy Public Key</button>
        <script>
            function copyToClipboard(element){
                var $temp = $("<input>");
                $("body").append($temp);
                $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                $temp.remove();
            }
        </script>
```

The result[image]

Also, is there any way of centring this block of text and aligning the text to the left? I've tried all the solutions from questions addressing a similar issue, but none of them is working for me. (shall I create another question for this?)

Comment: use `.replace(/\s/g, "")` to remove all white spaces

Comment: `$(element).text().replace(/\s/g, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(element).text().replace(/\s/g, "")
```

instead of just

```
$(element).text()
```